# Dynamically modify element properties by ID using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, maps

I have constructed a function as follows which will change the color, in this case, of the United States, in my SVG map.

```
jQuery('#map').Map('set', 'colors', {US: '#0000ff'});
```

That function works for me.  However, given this array of country codes and colors

```
var ccArr = [["US","#00ff00"],["CA","#ff0000"],["MX","#0000ff"]]
```

How can I dynamically apply that data to the country colors?

```
for(var i=0;i<ccArr.length;i++){
   var CC = ccArr[i][0],
     color = ccArr[i][1];
   jQuery('#map').Map('set',' 'colors', {CC:color});
}
```

I guess I just don't know what notation to use to reference the Country Code as dynamic and depending on the array data rather than fixed.  Thanks in advance for any help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the object and set the key

```
for (var i=0; i<ccArr.length; i++) {
    var CC = ccArr[i][0],
    color = ccArr[i][1];
    var obj = {};
    obj[CC] = color;
    jQuery('#map').Map('set', 'colors', obj);
}
```

But I am thinking you should be setting it like this.

```
var obj = {};
for (var i=0; i<ccArr.length; i++) {
    var CC = ccArr[i][0],
    color = ccArr[i][1];
    obj[CC] = color;
}
jQuery('#map').Map('set', 'colors', obj);
```

Comment: That works wonderfully, and I appreciate the two approaches as well -- for my purposes I will go with the first.

Comment: just have a doubt for the second ! your are setting outside the loop

Comment: @Anonymous0day The seconds sets the colors all at once. Just assume that the library is smart enough to handle that. I have no clue what `Map` is.